# maven - Help me understand the tag naming relevance

Tags: maven, naming-conventions

I needed to add a MainClass to the manifest file in the jar that is generated by the maven. Searching on SO and else-where shows several options- 2 of those are

*Approach 1 : Add to maven-compiler-plugin*

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.mypackage.myMainClass</mainClass>
        <!--addClasspath>false</addClasspath-->
        </manifest>
        <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

*Approach 2: Using maven-assembly-plugin*

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>foo.bar.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you check, the manifest class config/instruction is under the `<archive>` tag.

My question is why is it under the `<archive>` tag? I don't understand the naming convention/relevance here for the tag. We are not archiving anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<archive>` in terms of creating some sort of artifact, in your case a jar file. `JAR - Java ARchive`. The Maven Archiver is mainly used by plugins to handle packaging. And you are manipulating that packaging process adding data to manifest file which will be inside jar archive.

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer because the developer of the maven-assembly-plugin want it that way.
 With some explanation: 
The maven-assembly-plugin is designed to create single distributable archives from your maven project. So the output is called archive. The "jar-with-dependencies" is an special descriptor for this plugin to build runnable jar (Java Archive) files with all dependencies packaged into it. For the plugin this is still an archive. So when you want to add the manifest with the mainClass to the archive you do this in the archive tag.